# Save all Data in array, Filter out duplicated Data, Compare Data between arrays and Removed the matched Data

Tags: arrays, perl, filter, compare

I have some problems regarding my script.
The problems are:

1. The value of $str or @matchedPath sometimes blank when I print out. It is not random, it happen only to certain Path in the table.txt file, which I can't figure it out, why?
2. How to print like the outcome, because I can't find the correct file location or directory of table.txt file because I have put all the path location in an array, filtered it and compared with the matched correct file location of table.txt, because of this, some location is missing when printed out.

Example path that the /home/is/latest/table.txt files contain, the bold texts is the wanted path in table.txt,

```
##WHAT PATH IS_THAT,Backup
a   b/c/d   B
a   b/c/d/e  B
a   b/c/d/e/f  B
a   b/c/d/g  B
```

Example path that the /home/are/latest/table.txt files contain, the middle texts is the wanted path in table.txt,

```
##WHAT PATH IS_THAT,Backup
a   b/c/d/j B
```

e.g. list.txt file contains,

```
rty/b
uio/b/c
qwe/b/c/d
asd/b/c/d/e
zxc/b/c/d/e/f
vbn/c/d/e
fgh/j/k/l
```

Expected outcome:

```
Unmatched Path         : b/c/d/g
table.txt file location: /home/is/latest/table.txt

Unmatched Path         : b/c/d/j
table.txt file location: /home/are/latest/table.txt
```

Below is my detailed script,

```
#!/usr/perl/5.14.1/bin/perl 

# I want to make a script that automatically compare the path in table.txt with list.txt
#table.txt files is located under a parent directory and it differs in the subdirectory.
#There is about 10 table.txt files and each one of it need to compare with list.txt
#The objective is to print out the path that are not in the list.txt

use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;
use Getopt::Std;
use Getopt::Long;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;
use Cwd;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $path1='/home';                                                      #Automatically search all table.txt file in this directory even in subdirectory
my $version='latest';                                                   #search the file specified subdirectory e.g. /home/is/latest/table.txt and /home/are/latest/table.txt
my $path2='/list.text';                                                 #there is about 10 table.txt files which contain specified paths in it.

$path1 =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$version =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$path2 =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name( 'table.txt' )
                            ->in( "$path1" );

my @symlink_dirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->symlink->in($path1);      #If the directory is a symlink, in my case 'latest' is a symlink directory
print colored (sprintf ("\n\n\tSUMMARY REPORT"),'bold','magenta');
print  "\n\n_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n";

if ($version eq "latest")
{
    foreach my $dir (@symlink_dirs) 
    {
        my @filess = File::Find::Rule->file()
                                     ->name( 'table.txt' )
                                     ->in( "$path1" );
        my $symDir=($dir."/"."table.txt");
        $symDir =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
        my $wantedPath=$symDir;
        my $path_1 = $wantedPath;
        function($path_1);      

    }
}

else 
{

    for my $file (@files)   
    {

        if ($file =~ m/.*$version.*/)
        {
        my $wantedPath=$file;
            my $path_1 = $wantedPath;
            function($path_1);  
        }
    }
}

sub function
    {

    my $path_1 = $_[0];
    open DATA, '<', $path_1 or die "Could not open $path_1: $!";

    my $path_2 = "$path2";
    open DATA1, '<', $path_2 or die "Could not open $path_2: $!";

################# FOCUSED PROBLEM AREA ##############################       
    my @matchedPath;
    my @matched_File_Path;
    my @unmatchedPath;
    my @unmatched_File_Path;
    my @s2 = <DATA1>;

        while(<DATA>)
        {

        my $s1 = $_;

            if ($s1 =~ /^#.*/) 
            {
            next;
            }

            if ($s1 =~ /(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+/) 
            {
            my $str=($2);
            $str =~ s/\s+//g;

                for my $s2 (@s2)
                {

                    if ($s2 =~ /.*$str/)
                    {
                    push @matchedPath,$str;                                      
                    push @matched_File_Path,$path_1;                                
                    print "matched Path: $str\n\t$path_1\n"; #I don't understand, sometimes I get empty $str value in this. Can anyone help me?
                    last;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    #print "unmatch:$str\n\t$path_1\n";                     
                    push @unmatchedPath,$str;                                   
                    @unmatched_File_Path,$path_1;
                                        }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (@unmatchedPath)
        {print "unmatch path: $_\n";}        
        foreach (@matchedPath)
        {print "\nmatch path: $_\n\n";}     

        foreach (@unmatched_File_Path)       
        {print "unmatch File Path: $_\n";}
        foreach (@matched_File_Path)         
        {print "match File Path: $_\n";}

        my @filteredUnmatchedPath = uniq(@unmatchedPath);                   
        my @filteredUnmatched_IP_File_Path =uniq(@unmatched_IP_File_Path); 
         @filteredUnmatchedPath = grep {my $filteredPath = $_; not grep $_ eq $filteredPath, @matchedPath} @filteredUnmatchedPath;
}
        print "@filteredUnmatchedPath\n";   
        print "@filteredUnmatched_IP_File_Path\n";

sub uniq 
{
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}



close(DATA);
close(DATA1);

print  "_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using hashes is much simpler here
here's what I tried:
you will have to replace `@all_path` with your array containing every path where table is present

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @all_path =("some/location/table.txt","some/location_2/table.txt");
my %table_paths;
my %list_paths;

foreach my $path (@all_path)
{
    open (my $table, "<", $path) or die ("error opening file");
    #we create hash, each key is a path
    while (<$table>)
    {
        chomp;
        #only process lines starting with "a" as it seems to be the format of this file
        $table_paths{(split)[1]}=$path if (/^a/); #taking the 2nd element in each line
    }

    close $table;
}

open (my $list, "<", "list.txt") or die ("error opening file");

#we create hash, each key is a path
while (<$list>)
{
    chomp;
    $list_paths{$_}=1;
}

close $list;

#now we delete from table_paths common keys with list, that lefts unmathed
foreach my $key (keys %table_paths)
{
    delete $table_paths{$key} if (grep {$_ =~ /$key$/} (keys %list_paths));
}

#printing unmatched keys
print "unmatched :$_\nlocation: $table_paths{$_}\n\n" foreach keys %table_paths;
```

## inputs

in some/location/table.txt

```
##WHAT PATH IS_THAT,Backup
a   b/c/d   B
a   b/c/d/e  B
a   b/c/d/e/f  B
a   b/c/d/g  B
```

in some/location_2/table.txt

```
##WHAT PATH IS_THAT,Backup
a   b/c/d/j B
```

in list.txt

```
rty/b
uio/b/c
qwe/dummyName/b/c/d
asd/b/c/d/e
zxc/b/c/d/e/f
vbn/c/d/e
fgh/j/k/l
```

## output:

```
unmatched: b/c/d/g
location: some/location/table.txt

unmatched: b/c/d/j
location: some/location_2/table.txt
```

Comment: I tried to do like this before, but I become confused, because the table.txt is always changing, i need to loop the each directory that contains table.txt under a single parent directory. Would you care to explain the line #taking the 2nd element only. Thanks.

Comment: @DanialHaris it's because you said `the middle texts is the wanted path in table.txt` I assumed it was always the 2nd.
the function `split` with no argument will split the line with a /\s+/ separator on $_ (here, it is the current line). the split will create an array, here (a, b/c/d, B), i'm then taking element at index 1, here b/c/d

Comment: if you have several `table.txt` I guess you could first go through the parent directory to find the `table.txt`files and push every path in an array. After that run the `open(my $table .....); `while<$table>` loop, foreach path in the array

Comment: yes you are correct, I wanted the middle texts. Oh I see, if I take element index 0, it means a, and 2, is B, correct? Regarding my script, how do you proposed if I need to loop different table.txt to compare with list.txt

Comment: if you want to keep the printing of the path, I would suggest to build the `%table_paths` with path associated to key, instead of `1`, in the final print, you will then print `$table_path{$_};` instead of `$path`.  Try this and let me know if you succeed ;)

Comment: but, with that method, you won't know if a path is present in several `table.txt`  I first chose this method because I didn't know you had several files

Comment: how do you split the path in the list.txt? what if the path is so long and the wanted path is the end side, like this wqw/asf/asd/b/c/d/e and the other path in list.txt is aass/sewq/dasdq/ddd/b/c/d where the "/" is not constantly split, how you do that then?

Comment: if you want to keep the printing of the path, I would suggest to build the %table_paths with path associated to key, instead of 1, in the final print, you will then print $table_path{$_}; instead of $path. Try this and let me know if you succeed ;)  - I don't understand, which path that I want to keep printing? the only thing that I want is that the unmatched path in the table.txt and the file location or directory of the table.txt after compared with list.txt

Comment: I didn't know that, from what you posted in your question, it seemed that path in `list` file had always the same format. Maybe, don't split, just put the path directly as a key and then test if keys match between `list` and `table` to decide whether you delete key from `table_paths` or not

Comment: you could try something with my code, adapt it and try to achieve what you want. I don't think it will need much work. I posted this code fitting with your original post. It's now your time to work ;)

Comment: @DanialHaris ok I couldn't resist, I edited my code, tell me if that works ;)

Comment: You are too awesome man! really, look how my code is? so long. you do it with a much simple way. Thanks man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179547/discussion-between-danial-haris-and-flying-whale).

Comment: how do i print for (my $i=1;$i<=%table_hash;$i++) to get this outcome         
 1) unmatched: b/c/d/g
     location      : some/location/table.txt

Comment: @DanialHaris I don't understand, my code already prints this, no?

Comment: yes, indeed, but how I can print the (number beside the unmatched: ...) , so everytime it prints , i know how many unmatched paths